# Finding the Minimum of $\frac{1}{2} x^TAx-b^Tx$

Tags: calculus, matrices, optimization

Given a symmetric, positive definite matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 2 \\ 2 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$ and vector $b=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 10 \end{bmatrix}$ I'm trying to find the minimum of $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} x^TAx-b^Tx$.

By my understanding, this should be as simple as taking the gradient $\nabla f(x) = Ax-b$ and setting it to zero. Since the quadratic function has only a global minimum for $A \gt 0$, the minimum should then be given by $x_{min}=A^{-1}b$ but for this special case this gives $x_{min}=(-0.7647 ; 1.6471)$ which, judging from the contour plots and the function value at that point is not the minimum (which should be at about $x_{min,true}=(-0.382 ; 0.824)$). Why is that? And how would one go about finding the true minimum in such a case?

Comment: Are you sure that you plotted the correct function $f$? I think you plotted $g(x)=x^TAx-b^Tx$ instead. This is why $x_{\min}\approx 2x_{\min,\text{true}}$

Comment: Yap, that was the problem all along...  Thank you!